# change the height of a vertical line according to the bounce height of a circle

Tags: html, css, alignment

I want to:

1. **Align the circle** (containing exclamation mark) **with the dashed vertical line**.
2. Make the circle **bounce along the vertical line while changing the height** of the dashed vertical line accordingly.

Can you please tell me how can I achieve that in `CSS`? thank in advance.

```css
   .pin{
  display:inline-block;
  align-contents: center;
}
.circle {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #ff5500;

  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: blinkingBackground 1s infinite;
}
@keyframes blinkingBackground {
  0% {
opacity: 0;
transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
  25% {
opacity: 0.025;
transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  50% {
opacity: 0.05;
transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
  75% {
opacity: 0.075;
transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  100% {
opacity: 1;
  }
}

.vline{
border-left: 1px dashed orangered;
height: 50px;
position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="pin">
    <div class="circle">
     ! 
    </div>
    <div class="vline"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain more what bouncing along the vertical line means? Do you mean that after the first bounce the line gets a bit shorter and so on (until the line has zero height?)

Comment: @AHaworth I mean that as the circle will translate its position along Y axis, the height of the dashed line has to be decreased propotionally to give an impression that this dashed line is a kind of trait of the bouncing circle.

Comment: So the circle itself does not go continuously downwards - just bounces a bit - and the dotted line looks like it's part of it so goes up and down with it? [I thought at first that this was to look like a hammer on a nail, but it's more like a balloon and its string]

Comment: Do you need to bother to do anything with the vertical line - apart from center it. If the circle just goes over it it will apper to shrink.

Comment: @AHaworth unless if the height of the line is way longer than the circle, which may be the case.

Comment: So I definitely don't understand what is required now! If it's longer, who cares, the ball with overwrite the bit that the ball needs to overwrite, leaving lots of the rest of the tail there.

Comment: @AHaworth I want to hide the rest of the line  `--O--------` which may appear above the circle in case the circle went below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**#1 Align circle with line**
For your `.vline` class add those two properties. Width in order to have the one pixel width from your border. And `margin: 0 auto` will center your div inside the parent div.

```css
width: 1px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

**#2 Reduce height while bouncing**
Just add another animation to your `.vline` class.
In the example below I also changed the height from `50px` to `0`, that's keeping the .vline at zero pixels after animation is done. And instead I'm setting at keyframe 0% the height to 50px.

Depending on how many pixels you want to reduce it, you will need more keyframes. In the example I've reduced the height by 10px per second, so I have 5 keyframes with 10px steps.

```css
@keyframes reduceHeight {
  0% {
    height: 50px;
  }
  20% {
    height: 40px;
  }
  40% {
    height: 30px;
  }
  60% {
    height: 20px;
  }
  80% {
    height: 10px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 0px;
  }
}
```

And here the working example

```css
.pin{
  display:inline-block;
  align-contents: center;
}
.circle {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #ff5500;

  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: blinkingBackground 1s infinite;
}

.vline{
  width: 1px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-left: 1px dashed orangered;
  height: 0;
  position: relative;
  animation: reduceHeight 5s;
}

@keyframes blinkingBackground {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0.025;
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.05;
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0.075;
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes reduceHeight {
  0% {
    height: 50px;
  }
  20% {
    height: 40px;
  }
  40% {
    height: 30px;
  }
  60% {
    height: 20px;
  }
  80% {
    height: 10px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pin">
    <div class="circle">
     ! 
    </div>
    <div class="vline"></div> 
</div>
```

It's not perfect yet and you'll have to play around with positionings (maybe even have to add them to the animations), depending on what exactly you wanna acchieve. But it should give you a general idea and ONE possibility on how to do it. There might be different methods to do the same.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I want the height of the line to shrink from the circle side, and not from the other side. to give an impression that the circle is bouncing along this line trajectory.

Comment: Then you'll have to set a fixed height for the `.pin` element, position absolute the `.vline` on bottom of it and with each bouncing keyframe you also have to change the top position for your `.circle`